# IIS 6 immediate log flush

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, logging, iis-6

In troubleshooting an issue with a web service, I need to examine the HTTP log created by **IIS 6** on a **Win2003** box. As I'm sure you are aware there is a log buffer that prevents writing to file every request for the sake of performance.

*Can this HTTP log buffer be manually flushed, or temporarily disabled so each request is written to the log file in real-time?*

I realise than on IIS 7 you can do a `netsh http flush logbuffer`. This does not work for 2003/IIS6.

Additionally, this is a production box so I can't restart it, rendering the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\DisableLogBuffering` reg key hack (http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/flush_log.htm) ineffective.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll just have to wait for the logbuffer to flush on its own

Answer (score 0):

You're probably long past this issue, but if anyone stumbles across this in the future, you may have luck by adjusting the log file rollover schedule--since IIS will switch files, it will have to flush.

Comment: How exactly do you adjust the log file rollover schedule? You should include details in your answers rather than 1 sentence suggestions.

Comment: The log file rollover settings are in IIS Manager behind the 'Logging' icon--far more easily accessible than ’netsh http flush logbuffer’ which I have never heard of.  This isn't a technically challenging answer, more of a trick that people might not think of.